# Pandas calculate and apply weighted rolling average on another column

Tags: python, pandas, pandas-groupby, weighted-average, rolling-average

I am having a hard time figuring out how to get "rolling weights" based off of one of my columns, then factor these weights onto another column.

I've tried `groupby.rolling.apply (function)` on my data but the main problem is just conceptualizing how I'm going to take a running/rolling average of the column I'm going to turn into weights, and then factor this "window" of weights onto another column that isn't rolled.

I'm also purposely setting `min_period` to 1, so you'll notice my first two rows in each group final output `"rwag"` mirror the original.

`W` is the rolling column to derive the weights from.
`B` is the column to apply the rolled weights to.
Grouping is only done on column `a`.

`df` is already sorted by `a` and `yr`.

```
def wavg(w,x):
    return (x * w).sum() / w.sum()

n=df.groupby(['a1'])[['w']].rolling(window=3,min_periods=1).apply(lambda x:  wavg(df['w'],df['b']))


Input:

id | yr  |   a  |   b    |   w
---------------------------------
0  | 1990 |  a1 |   50   |  3000   
1  | 1991 |  a1 |   40   |  2000   
2  | 1992 |  a1 |   10   |  1000   
3  | 1993 |  a1 |   20   |  8000         
4  | 1990 |  b1 |   10   |  500    
5  | 1991 |  b1 |   20   |  1000   
6  | 1992 |  b1 |   30   |  500    
7  | 1993 |  b1 |   40   |  4000        


Desired output:

id | yr  |   a  |   b  |   rwavg
---------------------------------
 0   1990   a1    50      50
 1   1991   a1    40      40
 2   1992   a1    10      39.96
 3   1993   a1    20      22.72
 4   1990   b1    10      10 
 5   1991   b1    20      20
 6   1992   b1    30      20
 7   1993   b1    40      35.45
```

Comment: Are you sure your desired output is correct?

Comment: It may be off by some slight decimals, since i did it manually. But unless something is wrong with my window sizing, the answer below by W-B seems on target.

Comment: I think his answer is right, but it doesn't match yours for the second row

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`apply` with `rolling` usually have some [wired](https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/issues/5071) behavior

```
df['Weight']=df.b*df.w
g=df.groupby(['a']).rolling(window=3,min_periods=1)
g['Weight'].sum()/g['w'].sum()
df['rwavg']=(g['Weight'].sum()/g['w'].sum()).values

Out[277]: 
a    
a1  0    50.000000
    1    46.000000
    2    40.000000
    3    22.727273
b1  4    10.000000
    5    16.666667
    6    20.000000
    7    35.454545
dtype: float64
```

Comment: Do you know the reason why window size is 3, but the 2nd row is getting calculated?

Comment: @denutza since you doing with min_period =1 which means less that the window size still calculated

Comment: yeah, but the first row in "a" is matching, but the second row should also be matching original (since win size=3), but its getting the rolling avg instead --See my desired output.....unless im missing something

Comment: I get the meaning now..my desired output was slightly incorrect.